# Proper usage for "No X, Y, Z" sign?

Tags: словоупотребление, particles

I've created this sign for a bathroom in a property that I rent out:

[image]

(And yes, before you ask - I have fished several such items out of toilets in the past.)

Is the wording correct? I'm particularly uncertain about не vs. нет, but any other pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: my apologies for not reading the site rules carefully, and thanks to those who provided constructive comments. As one of them is that I shouldn't have posted just an image, but rather the text, here it is:

> Пожалуйста, поставьте только туалетную бумагу в туалете!
>   не  влажные салфетки
>       детские салфетки
>       бумажных полотенец
>       пластик
>       игрушки
>       и т.п.

For comparison, I have the same sign (with the same layout) in some other languages, such as English:

> Please put only toilet paper in the toilet!
>   NO  wet wipes
>       baby wipes
>       paper towels
>       plastic
>       toys
>       etc.

...and so I'd like as much as possible to keep the same flow. If indeed it's not idiomatic Russian to give a list with не/нет followed by a number of items, then so be it. But I would wonder: you find, for example, apartment buildings in the U.S. that have such signs outside (NO in large type, followed by a list of things not to do: ball playing, loitering, etc.); are such signs unknown in Russia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase with NO will be

> Запрещается + Inf.
>
> Строго запрещается + Inf.
>
> Запрещено + Inf.
>
> Строго запрещено + Inf.

But bear in mind that is sounds very official and angry.

If you mean to be more friendly, you can use the following:

> Просим не + Inf.
>
> Просьба не + Inf.

**Туалет** is the room, while a toilet is **унитаз**.

**Поставить в туалете** means to put sth. that can stand in the restroom, e.g., a vase, or a toilet paper roll if you put it vertically on a shelf.

To put sth. in the toilet means **бросать в унитаз**, **спускать в унитаз**. That is to dump things there.

**Бумажных полотенец** has a different and wrong case. **Бумажные полотенца**.

Answer (score 2):

I personally haven't come across signs in Russian designed in a model you mention. Rather it would be a simple enumeration of objects/activities with no fancy formatting.

As for the verbiage, the idiomatically Russian one would look something like the following:

> **Пожалуйста, бросайте в унитаз только туалетную бумагу!
>
>   НЕ БРОСАТЬ влажные салфетки, детские салфетки, бумажные полотенца, пластик,
>   игрушки и т.п.**

In case if by **пластик** you really mean ***plastic bags***, then it needs to be replaced with **целлофан**.

To model the verbiage in the English style you propose

> **Пожалуйста, бросайте в унитаз только туалетную бумагу!
>
>   НИКАКИХ влажных салфеток, детских салфеток, бумажных полотенец, пластика,
>   игрушек и т.п.**

But in my opinion this is not formal enough for a sign if formality is important.